# Open password protected ZIP in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, passwords, zip, archive

is there an library or a simple way how to open a password protected ZIP archive in Android? I know there are different types of ZIP encryption. I would like to open the most simple one, create in Unix with the **zip -e** command. The same file can be opened in Windows (which will ask for password). That should be the standard ZIP 2.0 encryption? How can I open it?

I search for all alternatives but I didn't find any final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a .jar library that works on Android and can decompress and decrypt ZIP 2.0 files.
http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

It worked for me (encrypted ZIP created in Ubuntu and decrypted in Android).

There might be a way to get it done without any library as described here:
[Implementation of ZipCrypto / Zip 2.0 encryption in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651442/implementation-of-zipcrypto-zip-2-0-encryption-in-java), but I was not able to get this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/

And there are several questions here tagged in Java dealing with Zip encryption you might look at.

Comment: I don't think that library will help me, it seems to decrypt only archives with AES encryption. The default ZIP 2.0 encryption is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at  [this library](https://github.com/ghost1372/Mzip-Android) that can zip and unzip files with password easily:

**Unzip:**

```
ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
zipArchive.unzip(targetPath,destinationPath,password);
```

The documentation of this library is good enough, I just added a few examples from there.
It's totally free and wrote specially for android.