# Android : Password protected zip support via ContentUri

Tags: java, android, zip, android-contentprovider

Java natively doesn't support reading password protected zip files. I have checked this [Open password protected ZIP in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750569/open-password-protected-zip-in-android) question which points me to use zip4j library.

I have different scenario here with following constraints :-

- I only get inputstream through contentUri (no reliable to query filepath) and zip4j uses RandomAccessFile for it's internal working.
- I cannot store file or can't hold entire content in-memory.

Using above rules , is there any way to read zip file ?

Comment: You could write the `InputStream` to a file; not ideal but it would work.

Comment: Yes but it will break rule number 2 in my question

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to convert between the two without storing local content. I think the only other possibility, not to break your rules, is if you were to take the existing code and refactor it for use with a `BufferedInputStream` or the likes. Even though the underlying API uses `RandomAccessFile`, I believe most compression formats can be processed sequentially and don't depend on random access, at least that's the case for the ZLIB format that I'm familiar with. I could be wrong though.